# Mysql Query Studied Days

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count

I have Emp table with following values

```
Emp_Id  Emp_Name    Subject        Dates
001      Smith      Java         07-02-2012
001      Smith      oracle       08-02-2012
001      smith      C++          10-02-2012
002      john       java         01-01-2012
002      john       SE           10-01-2012
002      john       c            10-01-2012  
001      smith      physics      04-01-2012
001      smith      c#           07-02-2012
001      smith     javascript    07-02-2012
```

Now as we can see here  smith studied only 3 days for month February and 1 for month Jan
while john studied only 2 days for month January.

How can we calculate this count for any employee?
As a e.g:Output should be in following way.

```
Emp_Id   Emp_Name  Month_Year   No_Of_Days_Studied_In_Month
001      smith      Feb12                 3
001      smith      Jan12                 1
002      john       Jan12                 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY YEAR(Dates), MONTH(Dates)` and do a `COUNT`.

TRY:

```
SELECT emp_id,
       emp_name,
       Date_format(DATE, '%b%y') AS dates,
       COUNT(*) AS No_Of_Days_Studied_In_Month
FROM   emp
GROUP  BY Date_format(DATE, '%b%y'), emp_name
ORDER  BY emp.emp_id
```

Comment: SELECT Emp.Emp_Name,COUNT(Emp.date),DATE_FORMAT(Emp.date,'%b%y')AS Dates
FROM
Emp
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Emp.date,'%b'),Emp.Emp_Name
This query gives me wrong output if we have number of records for same day.  Plz see my updated table values of Emp.

Comment: @PravinGate You don't need the `Emp.Emp_Name` in the `group by` fields.

Comment: yes I have tried that also. plz go through this [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4ac0/5 ... and tel me If I am doing wrong

Comment: No. I need output as I have mentioned in my post. As smith only studied for 3 days.(Though he studied number of subject in a day )it will be considered as one day only.

Comment: Finally I got answer ,we just need to include distinct when we are taking count, so our final query will be                        SELECT Emp.Emp_Name,COUNT(Distinct Emp.date),DATE_FORMAT(Emp.date,'%b%y')AS Dates FROM Emp GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Emp.date,'%b'),Emp.Emp_Name